# Is this message box apparently from discovery.com legitimate?

Tags: security, website

When viewing a "Know your meme" page about the honey badger, I got the following message:

> To view this page, you must log in to this area on
>   static.stg.discoverymedia.com:80:
>
> WARNING: To protect the system from unauthorized use and to ensure
>   that the system is functioning properly, all activities are monitored
>   and recorded. Use of this system is expressed consent to such
>   monitoring and recording. Any unauthorized access or use is prohibited
>   and may be subject to criminal and civil penalties.
>
> Your password will be sent unencrypted.
>
> Name:
>
> Password:

Is this legitimate, or a scam?

Others have come across this issue, according to http://community.discovery.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/1331921028/m/5381920699

I tried googling for portions of the message (eg `to such monitoring and recording. Any unauthorized access or use is prohibited`), and it does appear to sometimes occur on their website.

Comment: It means they did a poor job designing and developing their website.

Comment: This question is off-topic as per the SuperUser [FaQ] but as BBlake mentioned above it sounds like somone screwed up on the website's end.